# DXF→element only

Tags: regex, dxf

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad english!

What I have tried:

DXF file

Find: \r\n

Replace: @@@

Find: (.*)(?=ENTITIES)

Replace: $2

Find: @@@

Replace: \n

Find: ENTITIES

Replace: 0\nSECTION\n2\n\ENTITIES

replace - Currently 4 times

I want to replace only once

Comment: How could you run `(.*)(?=ENTITIES)` -> `$2` replacement? There is no Group 2 in your pattern. Please clarify in words what you are doing and supply a sample text + expected output. I understand you are using Notepad++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(AWK)

```
BEGIN{isw=0;print"  0";print"SECTION";print"  2";}
/^ENTITIES$/{isw=1}
isw==1{print $0}
```

Comment: Simply posting some code isn't terribly helpful. Can you explain your code? That way others can understand and learn from your answer instead of just copying & pasting some code from the web.